# Binding List to ItemsControl: How to refresh

Tags: wpf, binding, itemscontrol

I am binding a List to an ItemsControl. I shows up fine. But when I add a string to the list the control is not updated. I tried to raise the PropertyChanged event to force the update but that does not help. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="tt.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Strings}"/>
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Add</Button>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        Strings.Add("One");
        Strings.Add("Two");
    }

    public List<string> _strings = new List<string>();
    public List<string> Strings
    {
        get { return _strings; }
        set
        {
            if (_strings == value) return;
            _strings = value;
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Strings"));
        }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Strings.Add("More");
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Strings"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `List<T>` use `ObservableCollection<T>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `List<string>` to `ObservableCollection<string>` ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx)).

```
public ObservableCollection<string> _strings = new ObservableCollection<string>();
public ObservableCollection<string> Strings
{
    get { return _strings; }
    set
    {
        if (_strings == value) return;
        _strings = value;
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Strings"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Something that you might want to add: As a little background info, any collection type (usually, that even includes anything implementing [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9eekhta0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) that properly implements [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will do.

Comment: One more question: Why didn't raising the event help?

Comment: @JohannesSchacht because `List<T>` doesn't support change notifications. You should use collection that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

Comment: @kmatyaszek: I did that and that worked :-) 
But I think raising the PropertyChanged event would trigger a refresh to the ItemsControl. If I reassign the List it will also raise that event.